# I am looking for an expression similar to "J'ai l'honneur" ?

Tags: expressions, synonymes

I am writing an administrative letter in French.

I would like to avoid to use “j'ai l'honneur” twice.

Is there a synonym?

In the following context :

> J'ai l'honneur de vous informer qu'il m'a été donné de constater un problème au niveau …

Comment: Can you provide us with the sentences in which you use it, it's a bit hard to give you an equivalent without any context.

Comment: okey i will edit my question ... in 1 minute

Comment: The context is still not crystal clear but do you really need to use such a construct in your sentence. "J'ai eu l'occasion de constater un problème au niveau..." could work too and sounds 'lighter' to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Per se*, you could use similar sentence initiators, such as:

- « Je *suis très honoré de* vous annoncer... » (a)
- « Je *suis heureux de* vous annoncer... » (b)
- « J'*ai le plaisir de* vous informer... »  (b)
- « Je *me permets de* vous informer... » (c)
- « *Permettez-moi de* vous faire part de... » (c)
- etc.

But they are *not*, strictly speaking, synonyms, as they do not convey the exact same message — respectively (a) solemnity, (b) delight, and (c) reserve.

Now, in your case, if you are informing about a problem, it seems weird to use any initiator that conveys solemnity (so, I would not use « J'ai l'honneur de ») or delight.

I'd go with (c) reserve (« **Je me permets de vous informer** d'un problème au niveau de... ») or a structure such as the one suggested by @vc74 (« **J'ai eu l'occasion de constater** un problème au niveau... »).

Comment: so i was looking for *similar* expressions :) I will update the title .

Answer (score 4):

In this case, communicating about something negative, you probably don't want to use this formula. "J'ai l'honneur de..." is better suited for positive things.I would rather use :

> J'ai le regret de vous informer...

That said, as several people already stated, your sentence might look a bit too "heavy" and could be shorter while still conveying the same meaning :

> J'ai malheureusement pu constater un problème au niveau ...

or

> J'ai malheureusement constaté un problème au niveau ...

Comment: I regularly observe the use of "j'ai l'honneur de.." for negative things. It is rather odd, but acceptable.

Comment: Well literally speaking I don't consider it an honnor to announce bad news... There are so many alternative ways to express a negative thing I would certainly reserve "honneur" for positive ones, even if it's indeed acceptable.